# Understanding facebook api login with mysql database?

Tags: mysql, facebook, api, authentication

Can someone can give me some insights on how facebook's api login or any api login at all could work with a database mysql? For instance, I could write up a login/registration form and have the user input their information into my database, and when I login, it will direct me to a user's page with PHP's conditions of users password and username/email and it will go through my database to match if it is correct. Also, I can do various things in my site with user's information is in my database

But if the user does not have a username/email and password in my database, but I'm allowing them to access my site with facebook's api login, how does my site's mysql database run with facebook's api?

Answer (score 0):

U need to study OAuth / Oauth2.

Oauth (Open Authorization) is a Standard Protocol for Authorization and Authentication purposes. You can let User's use your API without asking for their login credentials.

[A very good link to study **OAuth**.](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/07/google-oauth-overview/)